# Issues with using hbm2ddl in development environment

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

I am using `hbm2ddl` to autocreate the schema by including this line in configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

I have a entity bean defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    private String fullName;

}
```

There are 3 attributes and I like the first two to be saved in database table and like to compute the third one. When I run `hbm2ddl` with option as `create` it's creating all 3 columns although I don't have `@Column` annotation on the third one.

How can I prevent Hibernate from creating the last attribute as a column?

Comment: Hibernate will always create columns for properties regardless of whether they are annotated as @Column. As you've seen the only way to stop this is to tell Hibernate explicitly that you want to exclude a property from the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Transient` would definitely stop it.

Comment: I never annotated fullname and I even tried dropping the schema and recreated it. @Transient did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `@Column` annotation doesn't mean that the field is going to be persisted. It just adds more information e.g. for the schema generator.

If you don't want a field to be persisted (and still, you use field access for your entities), you should either annotate it as `@Transient` as NimChimpsky pointed, or use Java `transient` keyword.

Comment: never noticed that before, I must have always been adding transient without thinking

Comment: @NimChimpsky well, of course there is a question what version of Hibernate we're talking. Perhaps before Hibernate was JPA compliant, its behaviour was different? At least that's what JPA 2.0 spec tells us about persisting fields: *"Mapping annotations **must not** be applied to fields or properties that are `transient` or
`Transient`."* and *"All non-`transient` instance variables that are not annotated with the `Transient` annotation are **persistent**."*